# how to make a table row to take particiluar number of data in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want when the items are selected from first table, the items are updated on the second table. However table 2 should take only particular number of entries. Here in this case, 2. Please help.

### HTML

```
<table border="1" class="table1" >
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Mango</td>
        <td class="value">100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><input type="checkbox" value="Orange">
</input>Orange</td>
        <td class="value">150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><input type="checkbox" value="Apple">
</input>Apple</td>
        <td class="value">200</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" class="table2">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text"></td>
        <td class="value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="items">0</span>
            Items | Total
        </td>
        <td class="total">
            0
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
        var x = $(this).val();
            $('.text').append(x + ' <br />').show();
} });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any research yet on how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do. Given that your HTML only contains a table, what exactly is being selected and what should be updated?

Comment: see i have made two tables just for the logic that the user whenever selected an item from the first table, that item name alongwith its value is printed or updated in second table.... but there are three items on the first table.. but i want second table should only take 2 items then it should not take further entries...

Comment: @AmandeepSingh Do you already have the code which makes the 2nd table update? If so please add it.

Comment: ok.. i have updated above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a (global) variable to keep track of how many checkboxes were clicked, and check if it is 2 or more.

```
var clicked = 0;

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        clicked++;

        // Check if there are not more than 2 checked
        if (clicked <= 2) {
            var x = $(this).val();
            $('.text').append(x + ' <br />').show();
        }
    } else {
        //remove the row again?
        clicked--;
    }
});
```